# getting undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to follow a tutorial to create a messaging app but while creating a conversation controller I faced an error. My goal is to check whether a conversation between the current_user and the selected user exists or not. If it doesn't exist then I want to create a new one.
but when I tried this I got the error from the bellow. It would be a big help.

The error log

```
 NoMethodError (undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass):

 app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb:30:in `conversated?'
```

My controller from Conversations

```
def create
  @conversation = Conversation.get(current_user.id, params[:user_id])

  add_to_conversations unless conversated?
end

private


def conversated?
  session[:conversations].include?(@conversation.id)
end
```

Let me know if you need any other parts added to the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are first calling `session[:conversations]`, the value seems to be `nil` and such `include?` is not a method that `nil` knows how to respond to. I think you can make a small tweak in that check like so:

```
def conversated?
  session[:conversations]&.include?(@conversation.id)
end
```

The `&` is a safe navigation operator where the method is only called if a value exists.

Comment: Just a note, `conversated` is not a word and you can use `conversed` instead.